# Remove soap header from message response

Tags: java, web-services, soap, cxf

How do I remove a

```
<soapenv:Header xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
```

node from a response message using Java (or web service configuration)?

I don't want to send back user name and password that is displayed in the header. Do I create a class to extend `AbstractSoapInterceptor`?

I am using `cxf bus to configure my web service.

Comment: Are you reusing the same SOAP message for the response? Why don´t you create a new one?

Answer (score 0):

I don´t know how are you receiving the SOAP message, but If you can use (or instantiate) a `javax.xml.soap.SOAPMessage` you remove the header element or attribute that is bothering you:

```
// Removes the attribute "key" from the message header
message.getSOAPHeader().removeAttribute("key");
```

Anyway, reusing the same message sounds weird to me, perhaps you should consider creating a new fresh response message:

This statement create a brand new message:

```
MessageFactory mf = MessageFactory.newInstance();
SOAPMessage message = mf.createMessage(headers, in)
```

This one, from Mime headers and an inputstream:

```
MessageFactory mf = MessageFactory.newInstance();
SOAPMessage message = mf.createMessage(headers, in)
```

Comment: I resolved my problem. For my particular scenario I had a webapp that contained both an <jaxws:endpoint and a <jaxws:client. The problem was that the header for the client was being passed along with the response from the endpoint. The cxf bus was required by the client but not the endpoint so I had to tie the bus to the client so that it would not be used by the endpoint. 
<cxf:bus name="clientBus"> <jaxws:client bus="clientBus"